# Cannot build from Xcode 11.7 to iOS 14 device

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

I already put 14.0 folder into Xcode11.7

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure that means you're trying to run it on a physical device which isn't plugged in. You shouldn't need to do much to run it on a Simulator.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to build in device

Comment: After add device support file make xcode Force quit and try again.

Comment: Issue this command in Terminal: `sudo pkill usbmuxd` to restart the USB connections. Alternatively, you can restart the Mac.

Comment: @HardikThakkar Adding device support is an unsupported hack. Have you tried it? Does it work with code 11.7?

Comment: From where you download device Support file ? Try to download device support file from this link "https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport", find device support "14.0.zip" and download that file only. Put this file in device support folder and ForceQuit Xcode and Try again.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d#gistcomment-3407135The Xcode 12 release notes effectively states that the symbolic link workaround won't work with iOS:

Debugging, testing, and profiling on devices running iOS 14, iPadOS 14, watchOS 7, or tvOS 14 and later requires Xcode 12 or later. Older versions of Xcode may display an error of “Failed to start remote service” when attempting to develop on unsupported operating system versions. (60850305)

Answer (score -6):

you should update xcode

xcode 11.7 --> 12.0

if the version does not match, the connection will not be made

Comment: If I update Xcode 11.7 to Xcode 12 it make result app is is different

Comment: This answer is not related.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't know the problem exactly